# JQuery Scrollbars Jittering On Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, scrollbars

I've recently added a great custom scrollbar solution from malihu (http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html) to my site. However I've noticed that on my mac, the scrolling can get very jittery when I scroll down. It's almost as if it doesn't pick up slow scrolls down, only fast ones.

I've set up a fiddle where you can see the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/qyrrm/6/

The problem appears to be specific to Safari on Mac, as I've tested it on Firefox, Chrome and IE7 (running under emulation) and they all seem to be fine.

If anyone has any idea what could be causing the problem, then I'd be keen to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a known problem, which the developer has already addressed, by releasing a patched version which lowers the delta for Mac Safari. Anyone else having trouble can download the patched version at:

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scroller_js_osxsafari.zip